# How to check reset session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis

In my application session is not reset if the user is active.

My session timeout time is 20min.

means: Let an user logged in to my application and doing some operation. That operation took 20 mins. then in the middle of the operation application showing session time out error and redirect to login page which in not good.

how to solve this problem.

How to reset the session when the user is active. If the user is inactive for 20 min then it should redirect to  login page.

If the user is ideal for 15 min and after that user do some operation then the user should not redirect to login page.

I found some link to set from IIS label which is not working.

can you please help to solve this one.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

if you are using forms authentication then following code will help.

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="FrmAbc.aspx" loginUrl="FrmLogin.aspx" protection="All" cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="1200" />
</authentication>
```